# How to make alert whether the given mobile number is valid or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The J query code was :

```
    allNextBtn.click(function(){

    //TODO: more validation if needs

    if($("#mobile").val() == ''){
        $("#mobile").focus();
        $("#mobile_valid").addClass('has-error');
        return;
    }

    var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
        curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
        nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
        curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
        isValid = true;

    $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
    for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
        if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
            isValid = false;
            $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
        }
    }

    if (isValid)
        nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
});
```

This is my code validating mobile number.. Here i need to give alert whether the entered mobile number is valid or not and how can i make it in the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below code:

```js
function validateMobNo(mobno){
    var mobno2;
    var flag=false;
    var mlen= mobno.length;
    //alert(mobno.substr(3,mobno.length-3));
    if(mobno.charAt(0)!='+' && mlen==10){
        mobno2="+91-"+mobno;
        alert("1>>your mobile wants to be in "+mobno2);
        flag=true;
    }
    else if(mobno.charAt(0)=='+'){
        if(mobno.substr(0,3)=='+91' && mobno.length==13){
            mobno2=mobno.substr(0,3)+"-"+mobno.substr(3,mobno.length-3);
            alert("2>>your mobile wants to be in "+mobno2);
            flag=true;      
        }
    }
    else if(mobno.indexOf("-")<0&&mobno.length==12 && mobno.substr(0,2)=='91'){
        mobno2=mobno.substr(0,2)+"-"+mobno.substr(3,mobno.length-2);
        alert("3>>your mobile wants to be in "+mobno2);
        flag=true;
        }
    else
        alert("Please correct your mobile No");
    if(flag==true)
       document.mobvalidate.mobno.value=mobno2;
    else
        document.mobvalidate.mobno.focus()
    return flag;
         
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="mobvalidate">
<input type="text" id="mobno" />
<input type="button" value="VALIDATE" onclick="validateMobNo(mobno.value)" />
</form>
```